# Error in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I built a chart in my application using the code:

```
var data = [];

// With various controls pose different values ​​to the item on
data [ j] . push ( {
      y : time,
      color: colors [ 1]
  });

// And after filling date
var len = data.length -1,
    series = [],
    i;

    for (i = len ; i> = 0; i -) {
        series.push ({name : "" , data: data [i ] });
    }

// And then
var = new char Highcharts.Chart ({
        Charts : {
            renderTo : ' container ' ,
            type: ' bar '
        } ,
        credits: {
            enabled: true,
            text: " powered by Macnil.it "
            
            href : null
        } ,
        title: {
            text: RagioneSociale
        } ,
        subtitle : {
            Text : Text
        } ,
        xAxis : {
            lineWidth : 0 ,
            minorGridLineWidth : 0 ,
            lineColor : 'transparent ' ,
            Categories : Categories,
            gridLineDashStyle : ' Solid ' ,

            gridLineWidth : 1 ,
            height: altezzabarra
        } ,
        yAxis : {
            title: {
                text: null
            } ,
            allowDecimals : false ,
            max : 24,
            showLastLabel : false ,
            gridLineWidth : 0 ,
            tickLength : 5 ,
            tickWidth : 1 ,
            tickPosition : ' inside ' ,
        } ,
        tooltip : {
            formatter : function ( ) {
                var data = this.y
                if ( data == 25) given = 24
                var minutes = parseInt ( (data - parseInt ( data) ) * 60 )
                minutes = (minutes <10 ) ? "0" + ( minutes) . ToString ( ) : ( minutes)
                var hours = parseInt ( data)
                if ( this.point.color == ' # E96D63 ' )
                    return hour + ' h ' + minutes + ' m in park ' ;
                else return hours + ' h ' + minutes + ' m at work ' ;
            }
        } ,
        Legend: {
            enabled: false ,
            backgroundColor : ' # FFFFFF ' ,

            labelFormatter : function ( ) {
                var count = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.yData.length ; i + + ) {
                    count + = this.yData [i] ;
                    return this.name + ' [ ' + count + ' ] ' ;
                }
            }
        } ,
        plotOptions : {
            Series : {
                stacking : ' normal'
            }
        } ,

        series : series
    });
```

But unfortunately gives me the following error:
Uncaught TypeError : Can not read property ' width' of undefined

How can I fix the problem ?

Many thanks , dave

Comment: I dont see any part that you are trying to read property width in this code. The error must somewhere else in the code you are not showing us

Comment: A little concerned about a few (variables?) or strings in your output above. e.g. RagioneSociale, if they're strings, need to be put inside quotation marks, if they're variables, show where it is being initialized. Not advisable to use the same variable names as the keys that are used in highcharts (Text) to avoid confusion.

Comment: I stated 

<div id="container" style="width:88%; margin: 0"> </ div> 

and I used 
$ (window). resize (); 

in such a way that the diagram always being the size of the div. 
I remember that before, about a week ago, it worked ....

Comment: Do you use any wrapper? because some of elemnets of this json are incorrect, like Charts whcih should be chart. Morever var = new char Highcharts.Chart({...}) is also incorrect, should be var = new Highcharts.Chart({...})